# Counting distinct lists in a list

Tags: python, performance, array

I'm trying to remove the duplicate from the list and count the list after removing the duplicates

```
seq = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
new_seq = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
count = 3
```

My code takes around 23 seconds for around 66,000 lists in a list

How can I make my code faster?

```
def unique(seq):
    new_seq = []
    count = 0
    for i in seq:
        if i not in new_seq:
            new_seq.append(i)
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to accomplish? Is this function part of a larger program? Tell us about the context.

Comment: The lists comes from another function which calculates an algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is slow because it is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>): each element being added to `new_seq` has to be compared against every previously added element.

To deduplicate a sequence, use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).  Constructing the set is only O(*n*) because it uses hashing.

Then, to obtain the size of the set, use [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

```
def unique(seq):
    return len(set(tuple(element) for element in seq))
```